# How to send values to popup

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

How to do this!? : when click on **Add** open **popup windows** with **1.php** content then when click on **Send** generate variable and send **this variable** and  replace content **1.php** with **2.php**

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but I'll try to give you a hint. Look at Query-Parameters - amybe they can help you

Answer (score 0):

Two separate click functions, two separate ajax calls. Going on the basis you have an idea of how to create a popup, the following would be the ebb and flow.

```
$('#add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: '1.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {q : 6} //or $('#someEle').text() for dynamic values of course.
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#txtHint').html(data);
        $('#popup').show();
    });
});

//since 'send' seems to be dynamically injected, we need an event handler.

$('#txtHint').on('click', '#send', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
        url: '2.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {q : 6}
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#txtHint').html(data);
        //popup is already open, no reason to fire .show() again.
    });
});
```